# How to use multiple scripts in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to load different JavaScript functions in my page and all these functions works properly one by one, the problem begins when I try to make all of them work together. The first script I write in the code, is the only one that works and others don't.

Inside `<head>` tags I have:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
$( function() {
    $( "#from" ).datepicker();
    $( "#to").datepicker();
} );
</script>

<script>
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('#from').on('change', function(){
        var FechaLlegada = jQuery('#from').val();
        jQuery('#to').val(FechaLlegada);
    })  
});
</script>
```

And then inside another page I have two scripts to control some datepicker functionalities:

```html
<script>
$('input.date-picker-1').datepicker({
    constrainInput: true,
    hideIfNoPrevNext: true,
    onSelect: function () {
    var dees = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() { 
        dees.closest('.fields').find('.date-picker-2').datepicker('show');
    }, 100);
    }
});
$('input.date-picker-2').datepicker();
</script> 

<script>
var dateToday = new Date();
var dates = $("#from, #to").datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: false,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    minDate: dateToday,
    onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
        var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : null,
            instance = $(this).data("datepicker"),
            date = $.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, selectedDate, instance.settings);
            if(option!==null){
                dates.not(this).datepicker("option", option, date);
            }
    }
});
</script>
```

The only one that works with this configuration is the one that begins with `$('input.date-picker-1').datepicker({...})`

How can I make them work all together?

Comment: Is there error shown on the console?

Comment: The script seems to be working properly. Any error ? have you debugged with alert and console.log ?

Comment: Yikes! I'm seeing that my console now displays multiple errors but all are the same one: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'inline' of undefined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.datepicker_handleMouseover (jquery-ui.js:9199)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery-1.12.4.js:5226)
    at HTMLDivElement.elemData.handle (jquery-1.12.4.js:4878)"